# How to export SSRS report having linked reports in to excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

I have a main report main.rdl and 2 linked reports like linked1.rdl and linked2.rdl as a drill through report from the main report.
I have deployed all the reports under one folder in the report server.when i view the main report its working fine and drilling through the linked reports. but my question is how can i export to excel which contains main report as well as linked reports as separate  tabs in the same excel?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to put a rectangle on your page and then add your linked report as a subreport inside the rectangle.

then hide the subreports unless exporting to excel by setting the visibility property on the rectangle to

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.Name<>"EXCEL"
```

or for ssrs2012

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.Name<>"EXCELOPENXML"
```

There are a few problems with this approach.  (but these can be solved)

Headers and footers are not shown in sub-report

Performance.  The sub reports will run each time you view the main report

the above assumes the drill through reports are only executed with a single set of parameters

Comment: what one can do if they want to add actions but within same tab, not different excel files ?

Answer (score -1):

imho SSRS is a presentation tool, Excel is also a presentation tool (in this case) so your chaining your presentation tools.

Why don't you call from excel your reports data source and drop it into each tab for each report..main sub whatever.

As your reports should be bound to a named data source (SQL\ view\ sp) for the report you would be calling that.

You can add your main report ....but you cannot add the 2 linked reports, they would show all records. So if you then make your linked reports, reports like main this would then work ie feeding them the key filter field...the children records for linked reports would filter and give you sub tab report you need.

If you cant do this then you have to rethink whole approach... if it was me I would code it so I got all three sets of data and then populated Excel with each tab...save n email spreadsheet

Comment: Downvoting this answer implies it's 'not useful'. On the contrary; I would say it's a good answer - the problem you're trying to solve exists because you're using SSRS and Excel in a way they're not really intended.

Comment: Any tool that acts as a layer between the user and the raw data source is a presentation tool. "Presentation" doesn't necessarily mean that the data is presented as read-only data.